# grpc/grpc.h file not found error when building flutter project in xcode 11.5

Tags: xcode, flutter, grpc

grpc/grpc.h file not found error when building flutter project in xcode.

I reinstalled and updated all Cocoapods. No errors.

From Terminal, already ran flutter clean, flutter doctor (see below).
flutter build ios returns the following message:
Xcode build done.                                            5.4s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:

** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
In file included from
/Users/.../ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/thread_manager/thread_manager.cc:19:
In file included from
/Users/.../ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/thread_manager/thread_manager.h:27:
/Users/.../Documents/name_gifts_v2_working/ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/core/lib/gprpp/sync.h:22:10: fatal error:
'grpc/impl/codegen/port_platform.h' file not found

```
#include <grpc/impl/codegen/port_platform.h>
```

1 error generated.

Comment: Here are the specific error messages inside xCode:
    #include <grpcpp/alarm.h>
error:
/.../ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/alarm.cc:18:10: In file included from /.../ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/src/cpp/common/alarm.cc:18:



    #include <grpcpp/alarm_impl.h>
error:
/.../ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/include/grpcpp/alarm.h:22:10: In file included from /.../ios/Pods/gRPC-C++/include/grpcpp/alarm.h:22:

Comment: xcode version 11.5
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.5 19F96, locale en-US)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.5)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.6)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.45.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!

Answer (score 0):

Installing `libgrpc++-dev` and `libgrpc-dev` packages fixed this issue for me on Ubuntu. Try to find equivalent packages for your OS.